# How to send E-MAIL to organizers in Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I need send e-mail to the organizers of a event in Google Calendar, think in that situation of a video conference meeting : A person create a event and set a location for it, but one of the guests that are in another place set a location too, and we have rules for the locations that need to be sent by email to the organizer of the event and for that guest that included the new location if that's the case. The problem is, how can I know the user that edited that location?
I have another question too, how can i get the last event that has been created on a calendar?

Answer (score 1):

> how i can know the user that edited that location ?

You cant unless you set up push notifications [doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push)

> How can i get the last event that has been created on a calendar?

[events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) has an order by parameter that lets you sort by the start time or by the updated.